Markdown shorthand url relative path
In a folder structure like this:
./index.md
./other.md

How ro best reference other.md from index.md?
I want to produce: <a href="other.md">other.md</a>
Options:
We are inside index.md:

full bare url: <http://localhost/path/other.md>

works, but this is not what we wanted, it is too long.


normal url: [other.md](other.md)

this works, and it is the obvious choice, but this is too long and we
repeat ourselves.


relative bare url: <other.md>

ideal. succint and would generate desired output. However, it doesn't work,
presumably because md doesn't recognize it due to lack of http



Is there a way to make something like option 3 work?

I don't think that's possible. From the CommonMark spec:

A URI autolink consists of <, followed by an absolute URI followed by >.

